# Cannot boot into ubuntu even fter running boot repair

Tags: boot, windows-8, live-usb, boot-repair

I could not boot into ubuntu so
i ran boot-repair from USB,
got the following summary
i still cannot boot into ubuntu,
http://paste.ubuntu.com/11455973/

Comment: you can not boot into Ubuntu or windows? Mismatch between your question title and text

Comment: what happens when you boot ? straight to windows or error when you boot ubuntu ?

Comment: straight to windows...

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported . It is a BIOS issue , see the "TROUBLESHOOTING

YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS

This is a common problem and if you do not get a GRUB menu , re-installing or repairing grub will NOT HELP

Every BIOS/EFI system is different, it might look like one of the following pictures:" section of the first answer